# How to distribute collection on shader displaced object?

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement

My well subdivided plane Object has a shader with a nice displacement.  My GN distribute collection as instances on points does not follow the visible geometry, instead it follows the level plane.  How do I get the GNs distributed objects to follow the visible geometry in Viewport Shading 3dView?

Comment: Well, if the displacement is done in a shader material, the answer is quite simple: you cannot distribute the GN objects on the visible geometry. There is a reason why shader displacement is only showing in rendered view: shaders are calculated at last before rendering. Modifiers to which _Geometry Nodes_ belong are calculated before the shader, so at the time the result is calculated the displacement does not exist. You'll need an actually displaced mesh or a _Displace_ modifier for that (and if the _Displace_ modifier is on the GN object itself, it needs to be before the GN modifier.